# Join two tables and if the value on the first table is null, but second table has values, take the values of the second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have users and groups. Each of them can be given permission to do something on tables (for example "SELECT", "INSERT",..). Now I want to have a table with usernames and their permissions.

- So if a user has no specific permission to `SELECT` form `tableA`, but he is in the group IT, which has permission to `SELECT` from that `tableA`, his permission on tableA should be `SELECT` instead of `NULL`.
- A user should be able to have multiple rights.
- If a user has at least one right (no matter if specific given to user or group) it should display all rights
- If a user has no rights, it should display NULL

Here are my example tables:

- `MEWO\STFL` is in NO group and got specific permission to `select/insert`
- `MEWO\GEIM` is in group `IT` and got specific permission to `insert`
- `MEWO\WAD` is in group `IT` and got specific permission to `select`
- `MEWO\OZF` is in group `IT` but got NO specific permission
- `MEWO\BIA` is NO group `IT` and got NO specific permission
- `IT` is a group and got permission to `select`

#### Table 1 (permission of sinlge users)

[image: table1]

#### Table 2 (members of group with permission of its group)

[image: table2]

### Expected output

One table with following inputs:

- `MEWO\STFL` same as in table 1
- `MEWO\GEIM` has `insert/select`
- `MEWO\WAD` same as in table 1
- `MEWO\OZF` has `select`, **INSTEAD** null
- `MEWO\BIA` has `NULL`

> **UNION** both tables already gets me close but there are duplicates.

Comment: Edit the question add your expected output also.

Comment: @YogeshSharma is that enought or is there anything else you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified query to capture what you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE(PermissionName varchar(20), DName varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE1
SELECT 'INSERT', 'MEWO\STFL' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SELECT', 'MEWO\STFL' UNION ALL
SELECT  NULL, 'MEWO\BIA' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SELECT', 'MEWO\WAD' UNION ALL
SELECT 'INSERT', 'MEWO\GEIM' UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'MEWO\OZF' 



DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE(PermissionName varchar(20), UserName varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE2
SELECT 'SELECT', 'MEWO\WAD' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SELECT', 'MEWO\GEIM' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SELECT', 'MEWO\OZF' 



;with Permission as
(
SELECT DName,  PermissionName, RowNum=ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION BY DName ORDER BY LEN(PermissionName) DESC)

        FROM 
        (
            select * from @TABLE1
            union 
            select * from @TABLE2
        )g

)




SELECT  
    PM.DName, 
    PC1.PermissionName+
    CASE WHEN PC2.PermissionName IS NOT NULL  THEN '/'+PC2.PermissionName
    ELSE ''
    END
from
 (SELECT DISTINCT DName FROM Permission) PM

 LEFT JOIN Permission PC1 ON
    PC1.DName=PM.DName
    AND
    PC1.RowNum=1

 LEFT JOIN Permission PC2 ON  ---depending on the number of permissions you might have to add more joins
    PC2.DName=PM.DName
    AND
    PC2.RowNum=2
 order by
 1
```

Result below:[image]

Comment: Hi David, see this modified answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `coalesce()` function :

```
select coalesce(t1.permission_name, t2.permission_name) as permission_name ,
       t1.name
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.name = t2.username;
```

For your current attempt i didn't find any `P` alise.

**EDIT** : Perhaps you need `FULL OUTER JOIN` but your expected output doesn't suggests this.

```
select coalesce(t1.permission_name, t2.permission_name) as permission_name ,
           t1.name
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.name = t2.username;
```

**EDIT :** I guess you want row_number function :

```
with t as (
     select permission_name, name
     from table1
     union all
     select permission_name, username
     from table1
)   

select top (1) with ties *
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by name, permission_name order by name);
```

Comment: @Grimm I think you are close to my solution. I edited my question because I forgot something :/

Comment: +1 for coalesce(), but maybe he should do a full join. Thus the query will return values even if t1 is the only table having values for a specific entry (and t2 is lacking this entry).

Comment: @DavidWalser I edited my comment also because a FULL JOIN will be much simpler than a UNION on two LEFT JOINs ;-)

Comment: @DavidWalser ah ok, I see your edit. Then you can simply do a LEFT JOIN (table1 LEFT JOIN table2) and then use COALESCE() as Yogesh Sharma proposed.

Comment: @Grimm what shall I LEFT JOIN (table1 LEFT JOIN table2) with?

Comment: I read your edit again and must admit that I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve (isn't "... but if the value of the first table is null, it should ignore it..." and "...the first one is NULL, but the second table has values..." contradictory?)

Comment: I edited my question, my problem should be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this satisfies your conditions:

```
SELECT
    permission_name
    , name
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        coalesce(t2.permission_name, t1.permission_name) as permission_name
        , t1.name AS name
    FROM 
        table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON t1.name = t2.username
    ) AS _temp
WHERE
    NOT _temp.permission_name IS NULL
```

I assume you don't want rows where t1.permission_name is null and t2.permission_name is also NULL or even t2 doesn't have a row for this entry - hence the outer query (_temp). If you don't need that just remove the outer query entirely.

Comment: user can have multiple permissions so unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I will edit my question

Comment: so the question is edited. It should be very clear now.